# Calculate unique combinations of values in dataframe, and summary values

Tags: r, count, unique, summarization

I would like to work with unique combinations of `var1` and `var2` in my dataframe:

```
foo <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                  var2 = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3))
```

As has been noted, `unique(foo)` results in this:

```
      var1  var2
 1    1     1
 2    2     1
 3    2     2
 4    3     1
 5    3     2
 6    4     2
 7    4     3
```

Based on the unique combinations, how do I get:

- `n`, the number of occurrences of a `var1` value and
- `svar`, the sum of each `var1` value's `var2` values.

The output could look like this:

```
      var1  n    svar
1     1     1    1
2     2     2    3
3     3     2    3
4     4     2    5
```

Comment: extended answer to address your follow up Q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unique(foo)` should give you what you are after here.

UPDATE 2014: use `dplyr` instead of `plyr`

I recommend looking into the library `plyr` for other aggregating type tasks, or the base R equivalents of `tapply()`, `aggregate()` et al.

While redundant for this exercise, here's how you would use plyr:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(foo, .(var1), unique)
```

Note you can replace unique with any number of functions, such as finding the mean and sd of var2 like so:

```
ddply(foo, .(var1), summarise, mean = mean(var2), sd = sd(var2))
```

**Response to edit**

Now you have a more legitimate use for `plyr()`. Taking what we learned from above:

```
x <- unique(foo)
```

combined with plyr:

```
ddply(x, .(var1), summarise, n = length(var2), sum = sum(var2))
```

Should give you what you are after.

Comment: (`plyr` was superseded in 2014 by `dplyr` and since in turn by the tidyverse of `tidyr` and related packages)

Comment: @smci - if you have the energy, feel free to edit my answer to include the more modern tools. I've personally moved on to `data.table` but the `tidyverse` packages largely accomplish similar goals.

Comment: Just tell people to use `dplyr` not `plyr`, these days

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand your question well, try:

```
unique(foo)
```

---

**After question was edited:**

Not to write the same as @Chase, a very simple but not too elegant solution could be:

```
foo$var12 <- paste(foo$var1, foo$var2, sep='|')      # the two variables combined to one
table(foo$var12)                                     # and showing its frequencies
```

And the output is a table of course:

```
 1|1 2|1 2|2 3|1 3|2 4|2 4|3 
   2   2   2   2   3   2   2
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers are different than you state, but I trust my code more than I trust your answer, and I cannot bring myself to commit the sin of naming a variable "sum":

```
 newfoo <- data.frame(
                 var1=unique(foo$var1),
                 n = with(foo, tapply(var2, var1, length) ),
                 svar = with(foo, tapply(var2, var1, sum) ) )
 newfoo
#  var1 n svar
#1    1 2    2
#2    2 4    6
#3    3 5    8
#4    4 4   10
```

EDIT: (hadn't at first figured out what Chase **did** try to tell me.)

```
newfoo <- data.frame(
                  var1=unique(unique(foo)$var1),
                  n = with(unique(foo), tapply(var2, var1, length) ),
                  svar = with(unique(foo), tapply(var2, var1, sum) ) )

> newfoo
  var1 n svar
1    1 1    1
2    2 2    3
3    3 2    3
4    4 2    5
```

Comment: I believe the discrepancy in answers here are because the OP was looking the the length and sum of the object `unique(foo)` not his original dataframe. Good point re: naming a column "sum".

Comment: I think it's because the "foo" in his code is different than the "foo" in his tabular presentation. There are 4 "2"'s in the code vector but he counts 2 "2"s.

Comment: The first tabular presentation is `unique(foo)`, not `foo`. The count in the table below also uses `unique(foo)`.